# Add Views to UIScrollView Programmatically

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, swift3, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have added the following code to my UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewBrochures.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let brochure1: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image1")!)
    brochure1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    brochure1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    brochure1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 400)
    viewBrochures.addSubview(brochure1)
    let brochure2: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image2")!)
    brochure2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    brochure2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    brochure2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 400)
    viewBrochures.addSubview(brochure2)
    let brochure3: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image3")!)
    brochure3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    brochure3.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    brochure3.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 400)
    viewBrochures.addSubview(brochure3)
    let brochure4: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image4")!)
    brochure4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    brochure4.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    brochure4.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 400)
    viewBrochures.addSubview(brochure4)


    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure1,
                                                attribute: .trailing,
                                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                                    toItem: viewBrochures,
                                                    attribute: .trailingMargin,
                                                    multiplier: 1,
                                                    constant: 0))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure1,
                                                  attribute: .leading,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: viewBrochures,
                                                  attribute: .leadingMargin,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 0))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure1,
                                                  attribute: .top,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: viewBottomButtons,
                                                  attribute: .bottom,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 10))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure1,
                                                  attribute: .bottom,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: brochure2,
                                                  attribute: .top,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 10))


    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure2,
                                                  attribute: .trailing,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: viewBrochures,
                                                  attribute: .trailingMargin,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 0))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure2,
                                                  attribute: .leading,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: viewBrochures,
                                                  attribute: .leadingMargin,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 0))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure2,
                                                  attribute: .top,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: brochure1,
                                                  attribute: .bottom,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 10))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure2,
                                                  attribute: .bottom,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: brochure3,
                                                  attribute: .top,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 10))


    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure3,
                                                  attribute: .trailing,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: viewBrochures,
                                                  attribute: .trailingMargin,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 0))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure3,
                                                  attribute: .leading,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: viewBrochures,
                                                  attribute: .leadingMargin,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 0))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure3,
                                                  attribute: .top,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: brochure2,
                                                  attribute: .bottom,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 10))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure3,
                                                  attribute: .bottom,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: brochure4,
                                                  attribute: .top,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 10))


    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure4,
                                                  attribute: .trailing,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: viewBrochures,
                                                  attribute: .trailingMargin,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 0))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure4,
                                                  attribute: .leading,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: viewBrochures,
                                                  attribute: .leadingMargin,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 0))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure4,
                                                  attribute: .top,
                                                  relatedBy: .equal,
                                                  toItem: brochure3,
                                                  attribute: .bottom,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 10))
    viewBrochures.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: brochure4,
                                                  attribute: .bottomMargin,
                                                  relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual,
                                                  toItem: viewBrochures,
                                                  attribute: .bottom,
                                                  multiplier: 1,
                                                  constant: 10))

}
```

And also:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    scrlMain.contentSize = viewBrochures.bounds.size
}
```

Note that I have setup my UIScrollView and my container view (viewBrochures) in the storyboard already, I just need to add images to the container, and then be able to scroll them vertically, because they don't fit into the screen. In the scrollview's container view, I already have 2 other views that need to be above these new images (images need to be below the 2 views, and all of them together (2 views + images) need to scroll together in the scrollview). These other 2 views have already been added in the storyboard without issues. As you can see I've created the images and added constraints to them programmatically. I've added 4 constraints for each image, one for leading, one for trailing, one for top, and one for bottom. The top most image I have constrained to the bottom of the view directly above, and the bottom most image I have constrained to the bottom of the container view using a greaterThanOrEqual constraint. I have also seen somewhere on SO that adding "translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false" to an image is needed when adding images to a scrollview in code, but I'm not sure exactly what it does and if it is needed.

So this code works for adding the images, but the problem is the scrollview won't scroll, at all. I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing this, so feel free to suggest me any other options. As you can see I used autolayout and layout constraints. If you can see if there is anything wrong with my implementation of it, any advise and/or correction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There are two main issues with your approach:

1. When working with AutoLayout you should not set any frames manually. AutoLayout does that for you and does not like it when you interfere.
2. When working with UIScrollViews and AutoLayout you should not set the UIScrollView's `contentSize`. As long as your constraints are set correctly the UIScrollView will automatically adjust its `contentSize` and scroll its content.

Also you do not really need the viewBrochures container view (unless it does anything except being a container for the images). You can simply add your 2 above views and all the images as direct subviews of your UIScrollView.

To make your scroll view work you have to do the following:

1. The topmost subview must have a top constraint with the UIScrollView
2. All other subviews must have a top constraint with the bottom constraint of the subview above them
3. The bottommost subview must have a bottom constraint with the UIScrollView

You also have to take care that the subviews do not become wider that your scrollview (or the scrollview will suddenly also scroll horizontally). To do that you have to set a `width` constraint on one of the subviews that is equal to the scrollview's width.

If you still have difficulties making it work have a look at this [blogpost](http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/uiscrollview-and-auto-layout/) I wrote some time ago where I describe a similar scenario than yours.

I also created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pixeldock/f1c3b2bf0f7fe48d412c09fcb2705bf1) with a working example.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I tried that, I removed the viewBrochures, and put all the views directly under the ScrollView, and I made sure that the width is not wider than the ScrollView's width but still no luck... It still won't scroll.

Comment: Have you removed all occurrences of where you do `frame = ...` and `contentSize = ...`?

Comment: @joern "must have a top constraint with the bottom constraint". But the bottom constraints aren't defined. Nor the heights (and I can't define them because I am using a refactored UIViewController) . I mean, I spent the whole day yesterday trying to make these stupid constraints to work. Implementing your idea as it is, I get all views with the same height of the whole screen overlapping each other. Unless it's Xcode 10 beta, because this is driving me crazy.

Comment: @MicheleDall'Agata Please have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/pixeldock/f1c3b2bf0f7fe48d412c09fcb2705bf1

Comment: @joern I had solved it already (finally!) adding the height constraint in IB to the collection view (and adding translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false to the same), but I am taking a look at your code. It looks excellent! I strongly needed that "subViews.enumerated().forEach" indeed. :). One thing though, I added a view controller with your code in a TabBar controller and.. it doesn't scroll. Unless it has to do with tvOS, but I doubt it this time. I am checking it right now.

Comment: @joern found it. It was tvOS, obviously, I had to subclass UIView to override canBecomeFocused: class myUIView: UIView {
    override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
- and also today I have learned something new.. Thanks fir the gist, very helpful!